# Crypt a message with matlab

Tags: matlab, file, text, message

I have one question.
I didn't work with MatLab before.
how I read a message from a file. text? and how I crypt and decrypt  it?
I need this work for my study project.

Answer (score 1):

To read text:

```
fid=fopen(filename,'r');
text=fread(fid,'*char')';
fclose(fid);
```

To encrypt you can use whatever encrpytion suite you want. look [here](http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/personal/matejka/wiki/doku.php?id=root:en:projects) for aes implementation. 
Very simple enc/dec algorithem is xoring the text with some key:

```
filename=('my_cypher.m');
key='Justin Bieber'; %some very secret key 

fprintf('\n------------Text-------------\n');
fid=fopen(filename,'r');
text=fread(fid,'*char')';
fclose(fid);

text(text==13)=[]; %remove windows CR for readablity
disp(text);

key=uint8(key);
text=uint8(text);
lenkey=length(key);
text(end+1:end+lenkey-mod(length(text),lenkey))=32; %add extra spaces for reshape.

fprintf('\n------------Cipher-------------\n');
cipher = reshape(bitxor(reshape(text,[],lenkey),key),1,[]);
disp(char(cipher));


fprintf('\n------------Decrpyt-------------\n');
decrpyt = reshape(bitxor(reshape(cipher,[],lenkey),key),1,[]);
disp(char(decrpyt));
```